# Find all positive integers $n$ s.t. $3n-2\mid n^{3n-2}-3n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $m$ such that $3n-2\mid n^{3n-2}-3n+1$.

The statement is equivalent to $$3n-2\mid n^{3n-2}-3n+1+3n-2=n^{3n-2}-1$$
Which means $$n^{3n-2}\equiv 1\pmod{ 3n-2}$$
I don’t know how to complete it from here.

Comment: Using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%243m-2%5Cmid%20m%5E%7B3m-2%7D-3m%2B1%24&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Problem 3 of Fourth round](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1711443p11036795). I believe you'll find the approach used by [UK2019Project](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/user/394622) in message #$3$ to be most useful (note that there's a problem with the proof given in message #$2$).

Comment: And if, after studying that link, you can solve the problem, please write it up and post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $d=\gcd(3n-2,n)=\gcd(n,2)=1$ or $2$
If $d=2$, then $n$ should be even, thus $3n-2$ is even as well but $n^{3n-2}-1$ is odd. Hence we cannot have $3n-2\mid n^{3n-2}-1$. So $d=1$ and $n$ is odd.

Let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $3n-2$, by Fermat we have $$n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$ Hence $$n^{(3n-2,p-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod p$$
Assume that $s=\gcd(3n-2,p-1)>1$ so by definition $s\mid 3n-2 $ and $s\mid p-1$, the latter implies $s\le p-1$ and because of the minmality of $p$ we have (from the former) $p< s$. Combining them we'll get $$s+p+1\le p-1+s \implies 1\le -1$$ A contradiction so actually $s=1$, hence $p\mid n-1$ but that would imply $p\mid 1$. so $n=1$.

Comment: Why $n^{(3n-2,p-1)}\equiv1\pmod p$?

Comment: $n^{3n-2}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ Now use bezout.

Comment: But why $n^{3n-2}\equiv1\pmod p$?

Comment: $p\mid 3n-2\mid n^{3n-2}-1$ This was derived in the OP